# Spheres maximize enclosed volume

Tags: calculus-of-variations, spheres

I've heard many times, that among all possible $2D$ shapes with given perimeter, circles enclose the largest area and among all $3D$ shapes with a given surface area spheres enclose the largest volume.

Why is that?

Does the pattern extend to higher dimensions?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_higher_dimensions. The pictures there give a good intuition as to why this is so.

Comment: I didn't know before, that it is called Isoperimetric inequality. Now I found this proof for $2D$ [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6eLdFxIj74) and will probably figure it out for $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Right, "isoperimetric" meaning "of equal perimeter".

Answer (score 2):

Here's just a little bit of intuition to understand **why** circles enclose the largest area.

Assume that a given perimeter = $P$
Let $A$ be the area to be found.

1. Think about an equilateral triangle with a side length $s$ and $P = 3s \Rightarrow s = \frac{P}{3}$.
   Hence $A = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \times (\frac{P}{3})^{2} \approx 0.0481P^{2}$
2. Now think about a square. Using the same argument as above $s = \frac{P}{4}$.
   Hence $A = 1 \times (\frac{P}{4})^{2} = 0.0625P^{2}$
3. Do the same for a regular pentagon to get $s = \frac{P}{5}$.
   Hence $A = \frac{\sqrt{5(5 + 2\sqrt{5})}}{4} \times (\frac{P}{5})^{2} \approx 0.0688P^{2}$
4. As $s \to \frac{P}{\infty}$, we get a circle.
   We can also see the value of $A$ getting larger and larger as the number of sides of the shape increases. This should serve as a rough starting point to understanding why circles enclose the largest area and beyond.

Note: This post by no means highlights a rigorous proof to the asked question. In fact, it does not even prove that $A$ becomes larger and larger as the number of sides increase. Moreover, it fails to consider shapes other than regular polygons. *It is simply an observational analysis that should serve as a **starting point** in exploring the **why** behind this interesting result.*